# Synchronize hash map with jcombobox

Tags: java, swing

Is there a way to synchronize the entry values of a hashmap with a JComboBox. This means that as i add put more items to the hash map, the JComboBox is automatically aware that new items can be selected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create your own combobox model by extending `AbstractListModel<E>`, implementing  `ComboBoxModel<E>`, `ListModel<E>`, `MutableComboBoxModel<E>`, and using  a `TreeMap<T, E>` as the nucleus of the model class (TreeMap instead of HashMap since the combobox model's data must be maintained in a certain order). Just be sure to fire the proper data change methods whenever data is added or removed from your HashMap.

Comment: Not going to be to easy as the order in a `HashMap` is undefined if I am not mistaken. And that is required by a `ListModel`

Comment: @Robin: True. I was thinking about that as well, and perhaps it would be better to use a Map that has some ordering such as a TreeMap.

Comment: Seems like a good suggestion, worth mentioning in your answer

Answer (score 0):

extends HashMap to implement Observable interface just put Observor update function in 
add method of HashMap and listen for update in your jComboBox

Comment: The class `java.util.Observable` is _not_ an interface.